# Help with computing message on TrueSkill factor graph

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, inference

I want to better understand the step for calculating the message from the game factor $h_{g}$ down to the difference variable $d_g$ on the TrueSkill factor. Such message is shown in the [Rasmussen's lecture slide](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/teaching/4f13/1718/message%20in%20TrueSkill.pdf) (page 5)

$m^τ_{h_g→t_g}(t_g) =\int\int h_g(t_g,w_{I_g},w_{J_g})
\times m^τ_{w_{I_g}→h_g}(w_{I_g}) \times m^τ_{w_{J_g→h_g}}(w_{J_g})dw_{I_g}dw_{J_g}$

I understand it from the operational point of view, as the difference between the skill variables. However, I am facing problems proving that the variance and mean of such message equals to (page 7):

$v^τ_{h_g→t_g} = 1 + v^τ_{w_{I_g→h_g}}+v^τ_{w_{J_g→h_g}}$

$μ^τ_{h_g→t_g} = μ^τ_{I_g→h_g}−μ^τ_{J_g→h_g}$

I suspect it is a Gaussian convolution, i.e., the integral of the product of several Gaussians... I look forward to see a full derivation of the resulting mean and variances.